# deque::shrink_to_fit memory guarantees

Tags: c++, c++11, deque

I was trying to use `deque::shrink_to_fit` after deleting a range from the beginning of the deque since I have tight memory requirements. However, it didn't work and I just saw that libstdc++ implements `shrink_to_fit` using the swap trick with a copy. That effectively means that instead of better memory usage, I get 2x usage for a while and get OOM-ed because of this.

I think this limits the usability of `shrink_to_fit` and I'm wondering if there are/can be any guarantees in the standard? I looked it up in a draft copy (N3035) and only saw the "this is a non-binding request...". I realize why it is non-binding, and also why it can't be done for `vector`, but from what I know about `deque` implementations, it should be possible to give some memory guarantees (and looking at libc++, it seems do to it in a smarter way). Are there no guarantees because they would be related to a specific implementation?

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work" ?

Comment: I mean the last sentence in the first paragraph. Instead of improving the memory usage, `shrink_to_fit` increases it twice and causes my process to be OOM-ed (yes, I know, I'm using way too much memory).

Comment: How do you see that shrink_to_fit doubles your memory usage ? What is your compiler ? If thats the case it a bug ...

Comment: What kind of items are you storing in the `deque`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both the libstdc++ and libc++ implementations of `shrink_to_fit` look conforming to me.  But they are very different, largely because the two implementations follow different class invariants.

First off, for those that don't know, `std::deque` is an array of pointers (typically `T*`, but a custom allocator can generalized that) to fixed-sized arrays of `T`.  The array of pointers could be treated as a circular buffer, or as a buffer that can slide the start of its data away from the start of the buffer.

This answer will concentrate just on the fixed length arrays of the deque.

**libstdc++**

The libstdc++ implementation has an invariant that there is never a empty array in the `deque`.  If a `pop_front` or `pop_back` creates an empty array, that array is deallocated during the erase.  This design reduces what a `deque::shrink_to_fit` can actually achieve, since the `deque` is always at or very close to a minimum memory footprint.

The libstdc++ `shrink_to_fit` performs a copy & swap only if it can prove to itself that it can eliminate an array by doing so.  For example a `deque` could be holding 1010 values backed by three fixed-length arrays with capacity 1000 values each.  The first element in the `deque` might start at position 995 in the first array.  Thus most, but not all, of the first and third arrays are empty.  A copy/swap will allocate two new arrays, copy/move the 1010 elements into these two, and then deallocate the old 3 arrays.

**libc++**

The libc++ implementation follows a slightly different design which is intended to speed [FIFO queues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO).  When a `pop_front` (or `pop_back`) empties an array, that array is not deallocated unless there is already an empty array at the front (or back).  I.e. while the libstdc++ invariant is that there is never an empty array in the entire `deque`, the libc++ invariant is that there can be zero or one empty arrays at the front and back of the `deque`.  The rationale for this is so that if a `push_back` (or `push_front`) needs a new array, it first looks for an empty array at the other end of the `deque` and steels it from there, before resorting to allocating a new array.  Given a FIFO queue with an approximately constant size, this design will reach a state such that `pop_front` / `push_back` sequence will never allocate a new array.  Instead arrays are recycled from the front of the `deque` to the back (or vice-versa).

The libc++ `shrink_to_fit` will discard the empty array on either end of the `deque` if it exists.  In contrast, libstdc++ does not need to do this, as the empty arrays never exist.  The libc++ `shrink_to_fit` does not attempt to further reduce the memory footprint by "shifting" the values closer to the beginning of a block via a copy/swap operation.

The result is that a libc++ `shrink_to_fit` never invalidates references, while a libstdc++ `shrink_to_fit` often will.  Note that the specification of `shrink_to_fit` is intended to allow the invalidation of references, though now that I look, I think it mistakenly does not (it would have to for `vector::shrink_to_fit`, and the wording for `deque` was taken from the wording for `vector`).

Both implementations will also `shrink_to_fit` the underlying buffer of `T*`, though this has a relatively minor impact as the memory footprint of the buffer of `T*` is typically much smaller than the memory footprint of the arrays.  Each libc++ array typically takes up 4096 bytes (1 page), while each libstdc++ array typically takes of 512 bytes.

I have no idea what the VC++ `deque` does.  But it will also implement an array of arrays.

As one can see, while all implementations operate on the same data structure (in order to conform to the complexity and invalidation requirements), there are still some significant design decisions that are left up to the implementation, and each implementation strives to deliver what it thinks is best for its customers.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I thought that deques are similar to vector by never returning allocated memory (although now that I think about it, it's obvious that deque can do it efficiently whereas a vector can't).